# Why Stackoverflow code to download file in ruby via http does not work

Tags: ruby

I need to download a tar.gz file from an http repository. I searched on StackOverflow and I found several code snippets but no one works. The problem is that the file is created in local but it has 0 file size.

Here a code snippet I used:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'fileutils'

class DownloadManager
    def downloadURL(url, destination_folder)
        url_obj = URI.parse(url)
        basename=File.basename(url_obj.path)
        FileUtils::mkdir_p "#{destination_folder}"
        File.open("#{destination_folder}/#{basename}", "w") do |f|
            IO.copy_stream(open(url), f)
        end
    end

    ...
end

downloadManager = DownloadManager.new
downloadManager.downloadURL("<my url>", "C:/CF/253.6.0")
```

What's wrong with this code. Why it hangs when download starts and file size remain 0?

Comment: This code works for me with my own URL.  (Well, after I remove the "...")

Comment: I tried now with several urls and I find I can download winzip for example, So there is something wrong with the url I am using right now. How I can debug it?

Comment: Test it with CURL

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo do you have access to the server?  what happens if you try retrieving with another command-line tool like curl?